# Combine elasticsearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently started learning Elasticsearch and am looking to combine two queries.

```
{
    'query': {
        'match': {
            'title': 'phrase'
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
{
    'query': {
        'range': {
           '@timestamp': {
              'gte': 'now-30d',
              'lte': 'now'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reading the documentation I saw that it is possible to perform this combination with **bool**, but I don't know exactly how I structure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bool is a container which provides four options

1. Must- It works like AND
2. Should - It works like OR
3. Must_not - It works like NOT
4. Filter - It works as AND but doesn't calculate score.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "phrase"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-30d",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about `filter`?

Comment: Good, yet in this case, it's best to move the `range` query in the `filter` section since it doesn't contribute to the scoring